# How to do page switching in Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I started learning Avalonia and all my studies came to a standstill because I couldn't find information on how to do page switching in the Avalonia Community Toolkit

I searched the documentation but there is only Reactive UI, not Community Toolkit

Comment: This is [one example on how you can make navigation](https://github.com/ibram-reda/NavigationApp) in Avalonia, and it's using Community Toolkit

Comment: @Ibram Reda thak you